# SQL Server - Creating User Defined Table Type - Creating User Does not have Execute Permission?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

I don't think this is a replica question - I've seen the other responses to questions of a similar nature here:

[The EXECUTE permission is denied on the user-defined table types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870320/the-execute-permission-is-denied-on-the-user-defined-table-types)

[Table valued parameter in a stored procedure gets execute permissions denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244217/table-valued-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure-gets-execute-permissions-denied-err)

My question is - how come when I create a User-Defined Table Type with a user, why does that user not have execute permission on it?

For example, I'm logged in with user myuser, using this user I create a UDT, and a stored procedure that uses the UDT. With the same user, I then try to execute the procedure, but get the error

'The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'MyUdt', database 'MyDb', schema 'dbo'.'

Now, I would assume that since it's the same user that created the UDT, this would automatically have the right permissions on it? You cannot use the GRANT EXECUTE command as suggested in the above posts, as you cannot grant permissions to yourself.

In summary - I wish to create a UDT, a procedure that uses it and be able to execute it all using the same user - why am I unable to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are being a victim of [Ownership and User-Schema Separation in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> By default, when developers create objects in a schema, the objects are owned by the security principal that owns the schema, not the developer.

Even though you've been granted permission to create an object,  the object it belongs to the owner of the schema into which you created the object (`dbo` schema). Knowing what the problem is, you can settle on one of the several possible solutions (eg. use your own schema rather than `dbo`, transfer the ownership explicitly, use [code signing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) etc).

Comment: Thank you for the swift and useful response - certainly makes for interesting reading. I have one question though; how come I can execute the procedure no problem (even though it's presumably owned by dbo), yet don't have the permission on the UDT? Why is the UDT different to the procedure? Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. I suspect is rooted in the fact that procedures are OBJECTs, types are not. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx. OR it could be that because the TYPE is used a parameter for the procedure (ie. *before* it executes) is not covered by ownership chaining. Or maybe you create the procedure with an AUTHORIZATION clause. As you see, I'm just speculating, I'm too lazy to test...

Comment: Thanks again! I'll keep plugging away and post anything I find but you've been incredibly helpful - many thanks.